# How to troubleshoot Magento when Developer mode errors out.

Tags: php, magento

I'm attempting to troubleshoot a custom module I'm working on. The website seems to work fine with no noticeable or logged errors. When I enable Magento developer mode I get a white screen. This points towards PHP errors.

When I check my server error logs I'm getting the following error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Mage' not found in /var/www/index.php on line 41
```

I'm not exactly sure what to do? Googling hasn't seemed to help much. I'm only getting this error in developer mode.

Comment: what does index.php's line 41 look like?

Comment: @OSdave line 41 appears to be the call to developer mode...  Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What version of Magento that you are using? It seems your index.php has been changed.

The best way to debug this, you can:

1. Compare your files to the freshly downloaded Magento code.
2. Check index.php on line 41, if there's code calling 'Mage' class

Just FYI, if the code exists and you need it. You can move the code after this code (line 68 on Community 1.8.1)

> require_once $mageFilename;

Hope this help.

Comment: Hey, Thanks for the reply. I'm running Magento Enterprise ver. 1.12.0.2. Also, I'm working on comparing files to a fresh download.

Comment: The problem was that I wasn't thinking and enabled error mode at line 41. Enterprise require_once $mageFilename; is on line 68.

Answer (score 0):

Try by adding the following line inside index.php at the beginning file.

$_SERVER['MAGE_MODE'] = 'developer';

Hope you will see the error message.

Comment: I only get this error in developer mode. Developer Mode is triggering the problem